# How do I animate fire?

Tags: animation, smoke-simulation

[image: Soul orb]

So I created this soul orb using fire and now i want to animate it as a character but I've got no clue what to do. I'd like to try and move it around but I don't know what to do. I moved the emitter and domain and tried to animate it's position moving but the flame stayed in the center where it was originally created. 
How to I animate the orb moving around with the flames following it?

Answer (score 1):

Don't move the domain. Make the domain big enough so that the smoke can travel as far as you want it to. Then move the object through the domain.